How elasticsearch split documents in tokens
Suppose I have webpages and I am storing those as documents in elastic search. Now i want to understand will elastic seach tokenize each word title as well as content? Or should we define a key in document for which elasticsearch will extract words and convert to tokens for that key. Also if it is tokenizing each key can you share sample format in which they will be stored by elastic search
   title: "Getting started with elastic search",
   content: "Elastic search is a popular tool..."
},
{
   title: "Top 10 latest techs",
   content: "This blog will discuss about top 10 latest techs in market.."
}]```

Tokens: keywords mapped to document ids in which they are found
"Elastic": [1]
"Techs": [2]



By default Elasticsearch index every fields presented in document. Subsequently it split your all data into tokens.
If you haven't not specified mapping for your index, By default Elasticsearch uses standard analyzer to create tokens.
As per your above documents, it is going to create below tokens with Standard analyzer

POST _analyze
{
  "analyzer":"standard",
  "text":"Getting started with elastic search"
}


Tokens
{
  "tokens": [
    {
      "token": "getting",
      "start_offset": 0,
      "end_offset": 7,
      "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position": 0
    },
    {
      "token": "started",
      "start_offset": 8,
      "end_offset": 15,
      "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position": 1
    },
    {
      "token": "with",
      "start_offset": 16,
      "end_offset": 20,
      "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position": 2
    },
    {
      "token": "elastic",
      "start_offset": 21,
      "end_offset": 28,
      "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position": 3
    },
    {
      "token": "search",
      "start_offset": 29,
      "end_offset": 35,
      "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position": 4
    }
  ]
}

You can refer this blog to know how actual data save in inverted index.

I understand this sample tokens but suppose there are 2 fields like title and content, how elastic search will separate tokens for both? How it will know which tokens are for which field.
